# LXC container bridge with host network risks?

Tags: lxc

I'm new to LXC containers and still very much learning what is what.

I want to run a container bridged to the host network (e.g. 192.168.0.0). This is required because the application I want to run inside the container needs to be on the same network. I believe my container is unpriviliged which I understand is the most secure (just the basic image when you run lxc launch ubuntu:x).

From a security point of view is this less secure then lets say a normal VM if I put the container on the same network as the host? Are there any other things I should keep in mind?